# How to Show Featured products by current product category

Tags: woocommerce

By default the widget shows all featured products from all categories, but it would be more logical to show only featured products from the category whose product or category the user is currently browsing.

I try this, but not work

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_products_widget_query_args', function ( $query_args ){
    
    $categories = wp_get_post_categories( get_queried_object_id() );

        $query_args['tax_query'] = array( array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $categories,
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            
            
        ));

        return $query_args;
    }, 10, 1 );
```

And this not work

```
/**
 * Featured Products only from currently category
 */

add_filter( 'woocommerce_products_widget_query_args', function( $query_args ){
    
    $term        = get_queried_object();
    $category_id = empty( $term->term_id ) ? 0 : $term->term_id;    

    
    $query_args['tax_query'] = array( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $cat,
    ));
    return $query_args;
}, 10, 1 );
```

And this not work

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_products_widget_query_args', 'r2gqo', 1 );
function r2gqo( $query_args ) {


    $category = get_queried_object();
    $current_cat= $category->term_id;


$query_args['tax_query'][] = array(

            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $term_id,
        );
return $query_args;
}
```

This not work

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_products_widget_query_args', function( $query_args ){
    
    
    $category = get_queried_object();
    $current_cat= $category->term_id;
    
    $query_args['tax_query'] = array( array(
        
        'terms'    => $category,
    ));

    return $query_args;
}, 10, 1 );
```

And it not work

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_products_widget_query_args', function( $query_args ){
    
    $term        = get_queried_object();
    $category_id = empty( $term->term_id ) ? 0 : $term->term_id;    

    
    $query_args['tax_query'] = array( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $category_id,
    ));

    return $query_args;
}, 10, 1 );
```

This work only for certains category

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_products_widget_query_args', function( $query_args ){
    
    $categories = array( 'music', 'posters' );
    
    $query_args['tax_query'] = array( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $categories,
    ));

    return $query_args;
}, 10, 1 );
```

Just a draft bellow

```
/* //draft
used before
    global $wp_query;
     
    if(is_product_category()) {
        $current_term = get_queried_object(); }
    $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( get_post_type( $post_id ) );
    return $wp_query->get_queried_object();
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining your one that works for specific categories only, and the draft that you had started. I have tried the following and it works for category pages and single product pages. So on category pages it will filter by the category of the page and on single product pages it will filter by any of the categories the product is assigned to

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_products_widget_query_args', function( $query_args ){
    
    $cat = '';
    
    if ( is_product_category() ) { // is it a product category page
        $current_term = get_queried_object();
        // get_queries_object returns a WP_Term object when on a category page
        $cat = $current_term->term_id;
    } elseif ( is_product() ) { // or is it a single product page
        global $product;
        // get_category_ids will return an array of all categories assigned to the product
        $cat = $product->get_category_ids();
    }
    
    $query_args['tax_query'] = array( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field'    => 'id',
        'terms'    => $cat,
    ));

    return $query_args;
}, 10, 1 );
```

Further to requirements, if you only want featured products, you would then use

```
    $query_args['tax_query'] = array( 
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    => $cat,
        ),  
        array( 
            'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    => 'featured',
            'operator' => 'IN',
        ));
```

If you are using multiple product list widgets the above will prevent them all working correctly. So you would instead use

```
    $query_args['tax_query'][] = array( 
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    => $cat,
        );
```

which adds to the existing tax_query instead of replacing it. Then you can set Show "Featured products" in the actual product list widget settings

Comment: Thanks, good code, but there was a small problem that I didn't notice right away - it shows all products from the category, when it should only show recommended products from the current category. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: I have added on a replacement piece of code in my answer, to limit it to just the featured products.

Comment: Thank you, now the list of recommended products works correctly. But unfortunately the code has affected other widget lists. And now the list of Products with Sale Price (On Sale)  also displays only the Featured Products with Sale Price.

Comment: Why not instead of adding the extra bit to filter by featured products in the code, select Show "Featured Products" instead of "All Products" in the actual widget settings?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean at all. Maybe I didn't formulate the task correctly, so I apologize to you. Woocommerce has a "Goods List" widget. In it you can choose which goods to show - "All Products", "Featured Products", "Products on Sale".  You need all of these things to work within the category whose product the user is currently browsing. Products on Sale = Products on Sale from that category. Featured Products = Recommended Items from that category. Maybe you mean you just need to add a new setting filter to this widget (Current category, All Category)?

Comment: ***Maybe you mean you just need to add a new setting filter to this widget *(Current category, Certain Categories, All Category)?* If so, do you know a way?

Comment: I figured out the code and it works like a Swiss watch. Thank you so much for all your hard work!